# access a class build in Web service in Android

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I know how to call a web service in Android . I just wanna know is it possible for me to access a class which is build in web service ?

For example i have a web service called XyzService,In that web service i have a class named Content. I want to access that class to create its object in android app.

Just like in visual studio we add service reference and we automatically connect to the web service. By using the following code in .net we can access the class of content.

```
 using webservice.xyzServiceReference;
```

And in Visual Studio i can access any of the class in that web service

```
Content c = new Content();
```

My question is that can i access the class in android just like we do in visual studio

I am using android 4.2 API 17

Thanks in advance

Comment: import package.of.your.class.ClassName and then you can use it

Comment: Vodich the class i wanna access is only available on web service how can i import a web service in android just like we do in visual studio ?

Comment: @AftabAli _Visual Studio_ is not a language, it is a development environment (and also important: it is not a runtime environment) that supports many languages. Please use terminology that accurately reflects what you mean.

Comment: @ mah Sorry for any inconvenience all i am asking is that how can i access a class only available in web service